# Why does RUNAS command work but PSEXEC doesn't in this case?

Tags: windows, windows-server, runas, windows-server-2016, psexec

When I try to restart a remove IIS, I run:

```
runas /netonly /user:mydomain\myusername "iisreset ServerBoxMachine"
```

It asks me for a password and then the command is ran successfully.  However, I use `PSEXEC` as below, it doesn't work:

```
psexec \\ServerBoxMachine -u mydomain\myusername -p MyPassword1 iisreset
```

It comes back with `Access denied, you must be an administrator of the remote computer to use this command.`.  So I ran `gpresult /r` to see if my login is part of the relevant security group and sure enough, it's part of the `BUILTIN\Administrators` group.  So theoretically, it should work.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you confirmed that you can remote with psexec by executing cmd with it?

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes, I did.  I actually found the solution.  See the P.S. in my post.

Comment: If you found a solution it should be in an answer, not your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing?

You need to run the command as the system account.  That requires you to add `-s` to your commmand

Your command would then be:

`psexec -s \\ServerBoxMachine -u mydomain\myusername -p MyPassword1 iisreset`

[PsExec v2.2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

[Additional Source](https://superuser.com/revisions/1290427/2)

Comment: This executes the command in the context of the remote machine's System account. That's not necessary when executing this locally...and idea why it's required remotely?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator The author determined that was their solution. Check the revision of the question.  Only made what was an answer, submitted as an edit to a question, into an actual answer

Comment: Bummer. I don't doubt it works. I was just hoping to learn something useful. (Don't worry, I won't shoot the messenger.)